# sed or awk to print between 2 patterns[excluding the patterns]

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following text..

```
[start]
this
is my line
[end]
```

My output should be:

```
this
is my line
```

Need help..

Tried a combination of :

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/p' $File  & sed -e "s/]/']/" -e "s/\[/['/"   $file
```

but it brings up the pattern too.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first and last line with

```
$ sed '1d;$d'
```

So of your input file just include the text you've shown you are done. If you need to find the part between `[start]` and `[end]` do it like this:

```
$ sed -n '/start/,/end/p' $File | sed '1d;$d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your requirement?

```
sed -n '/^[start]/,/[end]/p'
```

The equivalent to the above is:

```
sed '/^[start]/,/[end]/!d'
```